# Zend_Auth or PEAR::LiveUser?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pear, acl

I am going to implement ACL in my ZendFramework-based pet-project. It requires the use of roles: guest, member, administrator. Resources would be: modules, controllers and actions.

The project itself is fairly small, but is likely to grow.

I investigated the subject and have found a decent amount of ready-to-integrate libraries, but the most obvious leaders are `Zend_Auth` and `PEAR::LiveUser`.

Which one would you suggest using and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is already ZF based, the obvious choice would be `Zend_Acl` because you won't need a possible additional autoloader (hardly an issue when adding PEAR classes though as ZF follows the same naming convention).

`Zend_Acl` can also be used with the `Zend_Navigation` helpers to render navigational elements on your pages with respect to permissions to resources. Of course, that's not an argument, if you don't need this functionality (you didn't say).

Regarding `PEAR::LiveUser`, it should be noted that that package seems to be more than just an ACL component, as (quote) *takes care of the login process and can be configured
to use a certain permission container and one or more different auth containers.*. `Zend_Acl` does not provide any authentication mechanism. That's the responsibility of `Zend_Auth`.

Comment: I decided to stick to Zend_Acl, because it's simple enough for my current project, and fast to integrate. And I'm also planning to use Zend_Navigation. Thank you for the response.